# Where can I find Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe?

Tags: c#, opc

I'm developping a c# OPC UA Server. I'm building my server based on the "UA Sample Server" project, provided with the  [OPC UA 1.02 .NET Stack and Sample Applications](http://www.opcfoundation.org/DownloadFile.aspx?CM=3&RI=964&CN=KEY&CI=285&CU=43).

In order to generate the server model it seems I have to run an executable called Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe wich is not provided with the SDK. (I found that in the file 'BuildDesign.bat').

I tried to install "OPC UA SDK 1.01 Redistributables Setup" & "OPC UA SDK 1.01 COM Interop Components Setup" but I still cannot find that executable on my disk.

Anyone know where I can find that executable?

(We are OPCFundation corporate member)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model compiler will be made available as a standalone ZIP file within the .NET Stack and Sample Applications deliverable which we will be releasing in the next few days.

Please email compliance@opcfoundation.org and I will send it to you directly.

Nathan.

Answer (score 2):

It is not available it the SDK 1.02. I had to install the following to get the ModelCompiler sources:

"OPC UA SDK 1.01 Test Applications Source Code Setup"

Answer (score 0):

The ModelCompiler is now released as Open Source on GitHub:

https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-ModelCompiler

A tutorial on how to create new models using the UA-ModelCompiler can be found here:
https://opcua.rocks/custom-information-models/